# Pulling a radio button's value to display from a PHP file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

This is my first time posting so I apologize if I've missed something or if I get something wrong. I've also looked at other posts and although some are very similar, I don't think it's quite getting to the answer I'm seeking. I am also very new to AJAX (although this code doesn't really utilize a lot of AJAX I think) so any helpful insight into this problem would be greatly appreciated.

I'm trying to create a quiz template that calls on the data from a PHP file using AJAX after selecting a radio button and clicking the "Answer" button.

The general idea is that after the user reads the question, they select a radio button and clicks on the "Answer" button, the bottom part of the page gets populated with either the correct or incorrect string. It's easy to populate it with text and css, but my issue lies in pulling the right text.

Here is the HTML code block that sets up the form submission:

```
<form action="data.php" method="post" id="q1">
    <input type="radio" name="answer1" value="1a" id="1q">  A.  
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="answer1" value="1b" id="1q">  B.  
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="answer1" value="1c" id="1q">  C.  
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="answer1" value="1d" id="1q">  D.  
    <br>
    <input name="submit1" id="answer" type="button" title="abutton" value="ANSWER">
</form>
```

Here I've set up four radio buttons that each correspond to a letter and the form is linked to data.php, the file I'm pulling the correct/incorrect text from in this case.

I had an earlier version of the code that would follow the logic I had set out to do but would populate the correct text in another page. My goal is populate the a grey "Answer" box in the same page that appears after clicking the "Answer" button with text. The appended text is defined as a variable in the code as $correct or $incorrect, based on the user's selection.

The JS code block that calls the PHP file:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#answer").click(function()
                {
                    var test1 = $.post("data.php", 
                        {answer1:'1d'},
                        function(data)
                        {
                            $("#text1").empty(); 
                            $("#text1").append(data); 
                            $("#panel").fadeDown("slow");
                        });
                });
        });
</script>
```

I had help constructing this JS code but I understand enough of it. The goal here is that the "Answer" button, after being clicked, appends the text below the form element. This shows up as a small, grey "Answer" box from where users can read whether they got the right answer or not.

This particular line of code is what's bugging me:

```
{answer1:'1d'},
```

1d contains the right answer and when you pick any radio button and press "Answer", it still shows the correct text.

But when I try to do something like this:

```
{answer1:'1d',answer1:'1a',answer1:'1b',answer1'1c'},
```

The incorrect text, which is supposed to populate after choosing the radio buttons 1a, 1b, or 1c, overrides the text that's supposed to populate, even if the radio button 1d is chosen.

The PHP code that the JS code is calling from:

```
<?php
    $correct = "Correct";
    $incorrect = "Incorrect";

    if (isset($_POST['answer1']))
    {
        if ($_POST['answer1'] === '1d')
        {
            print $correct1;
        }
        elseif ($_POST['answer1'] === '1b')
        {
            print $incorrect1;
        }
        elseif ($_POST['answer1'] ==='1c')
       {
            print $incorrect1;
       }
       elseif ($_POST['answer1'] === '1a')
       {
            print $incorrect1;
       }
    };
?>
```

Again, any insight on this problem would be greatly appreciated! Let me know if I need to clarify anything. Thanks!

Comment: Is there only going to be one question on the page at a time so only 4 radio buttons for that question will ever be on the page?

Comment: Yes, only one question at a time with four radio buttons.

Comment: You said you have a problem with this line `{answer1:'1d'}` : "1d contains the right answer and when you pick any radio button and press "Answer", it still shows the correct text." It's normal, you never send the selected radio to your php page. Take a look at my anwser correctly and change your ajax function like i said.

Comment: You can't use same id multiple times as you used `1q` for each radio in case of radio name must be same not id ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, `id` should always be unique. So remove or change the `id` of your inputs radio.

Then, you need to change your ajax request to send the selected input radio like this :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#answer").click(function() {
        var answer = $("input[name=answer1]:checked").val();
        $.post("data.php", {answer1: answer}, function(data){
            $("#text1").empty(); 
            $("#text1").append(data); 
            $("#panel").fadeIn("slow");
        });
    });
});
```

Because in your code you never send the selected radio to your php page. And if you only send "1d" in this line `{answer1:'1d'}` your php page will always return the "correct" text even if you check another radio button. 

I don't know the jQuery `fadeDown()` method. Only `fadeIn()` or `fadeOut()`.

Also, in your data.php `$correct1` and `$incorrect1` are undefined. So `echo` `$correct` or `$incorrect`.

Comment: Yeah, I made a mistake when I was editing certain information out, thanks for pointing that one out! The jQuery code should be fadeIn().

Comment: You don't made one mistake but five. But your main problem is your Ajax post function. So change your code with the function i gave you and tell me if it works.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I changed my code and it works now. I made the following changes to the $correct and $incorrect variables. Thanks a lot for the help!